# How to set different vairiables for groups of radio buttons in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a MCQ test page with tkinter in python.

Is there a way to initialize/declare multiple variables as `StringVar()` inside a loop so that each question has its own group of radio button. That part is in `show_test()` function.

I currently have this -

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import json

class test_page():
    def __init__(self, master, file_name):
        global answer_json
        self.master = master
        self.file_name = file_name
        answer_json = {}
        answer_json['objective'] = []
        self.master.geometry("1280x720")
        self.master.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
        main_frame = Frame(self.master)
        main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Create A Canvas
        my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
        my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        # Add A Scrollbar To The Canvas
        my_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
        my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        # Configure The Canvas
        my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
        my_canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion = my_canvas.bbox("all")))

        # Create ANOTHER Frame INSIDE the Canvas
        self.test_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

        # Add that New frame To a Window In The Canvas
        my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self.test_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.show_test()

    def append_answer(self, qno, answer, type_):
        answer_json[type_].append({"qno": qno,"answer": answer})

    def show_test(self):
        with open(self.file_name,'r') as file:
            count=k=0
            data = json.load(file)
            for q in data['objective']:
                option = StringVar()
                option.set("None")
                lbl_qno = Label(self.test_frame, text=q['qno'])
                lbl_qno.grid(row=count, column=0, padx=(0,10), pady=15)
                lbl_question = Label(self.test_frame, width=30, text=q['question'])
                lbl_question.grid(row=count, column=1, padx=(10,30))
                lbl_marks = Label(self.test_frame, text=f"[{q['marks']}]")
                lbl_marks.grid(row=count, column=2, padx=(10,0))
                option1 = Radiobutton(self.test_frame, text=q['option1'], variable=option, value=q['option1'], command=lambda: self.append_answer(q['qno'],option.get(),'objective'))
                option1.grid(row=count+1, column=1, padx=20)
                option2 = Radiobutton(self.test_frame, text=q['option2'], variable=option, value=q['option2'], command=lambda: self.append_answer(q['qno'],option.get(),'objective'))
                option2.grid(row=count+1, column=2, padx=20)
                option3 = Radiobutton(self.test_frame, text=q['option3'], variable=option, value=q['option3'], command=lambda: self.append_answer(q['qno'],option.get(),'objective'))
                option3.grid(row=count+2, column=1, padx=20)
                option4 = Radiobutton(self.test_frame, text=q['option4'], variable=option, value=q['option4'], command=lambda: self.append_answer(q['qno'],option.get(),'objective'))
                option4.grid(row=count+2, column=2, padx=20)
                option5 = Radiobutton(self.test_frame, text="None", variable=option, value="None", command=lambda: self.append_answer(q['qno'],option.get(),'objective'))
                option5.grid(row=count+1, column=3, padx=20)
                count+=3
                k+=1

root = Tk()
test_page(root,'mydata.json')
root.mainloop()
```

Page looks something like this- [image]

Comment: Make a list and append the `StringVar` instance (`option` in this case) in every iteration. You can later access these instances through index.

Comment: Thanks! `option = [StringVar() for i in range(21)]` this line worked with me. I tried it with a dictionary before but it didn't work. Some kind of key error. So I didn't check it with a list.

Comment: Appending `StringVar()` in every iteration gives error btw, for me.

Comment: Could you be more specific, what error?